# Beans are null, rejected bean name by BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have problem with configuration of my App, every bean in application is null, all services are annotated by @Service, @Repository, @Controller or @Component. I noticed that beans are not created due to no URLs path identified.

Here is a log:

```
 21:41:23.913 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name      'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0': no URL paths      identified
 21:41:23.913 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.913 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.913 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.913 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.913 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'dataSource': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.913 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'sessionFactory': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.914 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'transactionManager': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.914 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.914 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.914 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.914 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.914 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.914 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.914 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.914 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.914 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.914 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.915 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.915 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.915 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.915 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.915 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.915 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.915 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.915 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.915 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.915 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'jspViewResolver': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.915 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#1': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.915 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'localeResolver': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.915 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'messageSource': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.915 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.916 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'environment': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.916 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'systemProperties': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.916 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'systemEnvironment': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.916 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'servletConfig': no URL paths identified
 21:41:23.916 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'applicationEventMulticaster': no URL paths identified
```

Here is configuration:

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name></display-name>
<description></description>

<!-- - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context. 
     - Applied by ContextLoaderListener. -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:spring/main-dispatcher-servlet.xml, 
        classpath:spring/spring-security-config.xml,
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Servlet that dispatch request from Controllers -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>logistic</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>




<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>logistic</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
              org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- General Configurations -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>




<welcome-file-list>
    <!-- First Page load -->
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<error-page>
    <!-- No found page -->
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errors/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>

 </web-app>
```

main-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- DataSource definition -->
<import resource="spring-datasource-config.xml" />

<!-- Mapping Resources CSS, JS, IMG etc -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- JSP templates and pages -->
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- Language configuration -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang"></property>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages/messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="customUserDetailsService"  class="net.kxyz.busbook.serviceimpl.CustomUserDetailService" />

</beans>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<!-- DataSource Definition -->
<import resource="spring-datasource-config.xml" />

<!-- Mapping Controllers -->
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.kxyz.busbook" />

<!-- Mapping Resources CSS, JS, IMG etc -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- JSP Templates and Pages -->
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- Language configuration -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang"></property>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages/messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

spring-datasource-config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<!-- DataBase ORM -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/data-access.properties"
    system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" />

<!-- Enables scanning for @Transactional annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url}"
    p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:db/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

spring-security-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">



<http pattern="/resources" security="none" />


<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />


    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"
        default-target-url="/" />

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/denied" />

    <!-- <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout" logout- url="/logout" 
        /> -->
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="md5" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

I tried to disable
     mvc:annotation-driven but it not changed anything. Can someone help ?

Comment: `<context:component-scan base-package="net.kxyz.busbook" />` All the beans are in this package or somewhere else? You need to mention all of those packages or use a wildcard

Comment: All beans are on path, I have no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem.

The CustomUserDetailService is annotated with @Service.

I created also bean in xml configuration

```
<bean id="customUserDetailsService"  class="net.kxyz.busbook.serviceimpl.CustomUserDetailService" />
```

I removed this bean from xml configuration and all works good.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
```

For more details look http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s11.html

Comment: Remove <mvc:annotation-driven/> and try again wiht this beans.

Comment: No effects, I notice that these beans also were rejected 22:33:28.267 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0': no URL paths identified
22:33:28.268 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0': no URL paths identified